# Reading a file into Ragged Array

Tags: java

My problem is trying to read the file that contains a ragged array. I think i am almost there but i keep getting a null pointer exception error. Any help or suggestions are welcomed. Here is my code.

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.*;
    public class Calories2{
    public static void fileReaderMethod(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {// This method reads the file and inputs the measurements 
        Scanner input ;
        try{                                                                                            // into an array of type int.
            input = new Scanner (new File(fileName));
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                System.out.println("File Does Not Exist");
                System.out.println("Choose another file");
                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                fileName = in.next();
                input = new Scanner (new File(fileName));
            }

            FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(fr);
            int row=0;
            String currentRow;
            while((currentRow = textReader.readLine())!= null){
                rows++;
            }
            fr = new FileReader(fileName);
            textReader = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String [] columns = textReader.readLine().split(" ");

            int [][] caloriesOfTheWeekArray = new int [7][];
            fr = new FileReader(fileName);
            textReader = new BufferedReader(fr);

            for(int i = 0; i < caloriesOfTheWeekArray.length; i++){
                String columnArray [] = textReader.readLine().split(" ");
                for (int j = 0; j < columns.length; j++){
                    caloriesOfTheWeekArray[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(columnArray[j]);
                }
            }
}
public static void main (String [] args)throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    fileReaderMethod("Calories.txt");
}
    }
```

This is the error i get.

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Calories2.fileReaderMethod(Calories2.java:36)
    at Calories2.main(Calories2.java:41)
```

Line 36 is

```
    caloriesOfTheWeekArray[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(columnArray[j]);
```

and 41 is the where i call the method that reads the file

File I am trying to read

```
    200 10000
    450 845 1200 800
    800
    400 1500 1800 200
    500 1000
    700 1400 170
    675 400 100 400 300
```

Comment: Post your error trace as well.

Comment: Do you mean the error i'm getting?

Comment: @Micheal yupp, the error thing you are getting.

Comment: Are you able to run this file as you haven't made `Calories2` as public, class containing main method should be public.

Comment: Yes i am able to run it.

Comment: What is line no 36 of your code and are you making sure that file exists in your current directory.

Comment: @MichaelRey - doesn't seem to be the exact code that you might be executing. What is `rows` in `rows++`? Also add the sample input from the file that you are processing to figure out things properly.

Comment: Yes i am sure it exists, I think what is giving me problems is the way im trying to read what is in the file into the array.

Comment: It is just the amount of rows that are in the file when its read. In the array instead of the number 7 i had rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is with the kind of initialisation you are using for `caloriesOfTheWeekArray`,

```
 int [][] caloriesOfTheWeekArray = new int [7][];
```

This will initialise `7` rows but wont be able to initialise your columns as you haven't specified them. And without initialising your columns you are try to access the column in line no 36,

```
 caloriesOfTheWeekArray[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(columnArray[j]);
```

Which is causing you a NPE.

So initialise your columns having length as `columnArray.length`.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < caloriesOfTheWeekArray.length; i++){
            String columnArray [] = textReader.readLine().split(" ");
            caloriesOfTheWeekArray[i] = new int[columnArray.length];
            for (int j = 0; j < columnArray.length; j++){
                caloriesOfTheWeekArray[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(columnArray[j]);
            }
        }
```

Also you are using `column.length` instead of `columnArray.length` which ia also responsible for NPE.

Comment: Let me know whether this has helped you or not.

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot man. The way its reading the ray is right on some parts and on others its not getting the numbers in the file right. But i think i can find the problem myself. Thank you.